# T-SQL : understand cursor for update of

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't know what the role of `for update of` is in a cursor in T-SQL.

I wrote this SQL statement:

```
declare @id int, @nom varchar(30), @age int;

declare cur_info cursor for 
     select id, nom, age 
     from info **FOR UPDATE OF** age;

open cur_info;

fetch next from cur_info into @id, @nom, @age;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if @age = 20
        update info 
        set age = 0 
        where id = @id;

    fetch next from cur_info into @id , @nom , @age;
end

close cur_info;
deallocate cur_info;
```

When I execute the code, the update was done but when I don't use for update of age the update also done I want to understand what mean "for update of" and if you can; I want a real example of using this

Comment: The `oracle` and `tsql` tags are not compatible in this context. It's either one or the other, but not both. As for the question... I'm guessing here, but I suspect it's a locking hint. Also, the cursor is not needed at all for this query.

Comment: thank you for you comment but the lesson of cursor is include in my school program so i need to understand it

Comment: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is always a good place to start...

Comment: I wrote it befor but I dont understand what's the role of "for update of "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution 
my problem is why when i write 
    for update of age
in the cursor I can update age and id , name.....
example :

```
declare @id int,@name varchar(30),@age int;
declare cur_info cursor  for select id , nom , age from info  for update of age ;
open cur_info;
fetch next from cur_info into @id,@nom,@age;
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
if @age = 20
update info set age = 10 where id = @id ;
print @age;
fetch next from cur_info into @id , @nom , @age;
end
close cur_info;
deallocate cur_info;
```

but when I use the 'current of cursor_name' after where then I can't update any column exepte var1 and the sql server give me an error "The cursor has a FOR UPDATE list and the requested column to be updated is not in this list"

example

```
declare @id int,@nom varchar(30),@age int;
declare cur_info cursor  for select id , nom , age from info  for update of nom ;
open cur_info;
fetch next from cur_info into @id,@nom,@age;
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
if @age = 0
update info set age = 20 where current of cur_info ;
print @age;
fetch next from cur_info into @id , @nom , @age;
end
close cur_info;
deallocate cur_info;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`DECLARE CURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> UPDATE [OF _column_name_ [*,...n*]] Defines updatable columns within
>   the cursor. If OF  [, <... n>] is specified, only the
>   columns listed allow modifications. If UPDATE is specified without a
>   column list, all columns can be updated.

A use case might be a table `Users` where you want the code using the cursor to be able to update `EmailAddress` and `TelephoneNumber`, but not `Username`, `HashedPassword` or `RegistrationDate`. `... for update of EmailAddres, TelephoneNumber ...` would prevent changes to the other columns.

Comment: the problem is I use"for update of EmailAddres, TelephoneNumber ..." but even all that i can update username and all columns like username password

Comment: @AyoubELKhaddari As your answer demonstrates, if the `update` statement doesn't reference the cursor then you can update any columns or rows. If the update is tied to the cursor using `... where current of MyCursor` then it will enforce the column restrictions of the cursor. (And I didn't know about `where current`. +1 to you.)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH